# EditText / TextView

Tags: android, textview

Как при тапе в любое свободное место, текст, введенный в **EditText**, отображался в **TextView**?
Изначально отображать **EditText**, вводить текст, по тапу его(EditText) прятать, после, на том месте, отображать **TextView** с введенным текстом. Правильный ли путь?

Comment: Нет, это какое то не качественное решение.. Можно просто заблокировать редактирование в `EditText` методом `setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необязательно подменять `EditText` на `TextView`, достаточно просто выключать/включать возможность редактирования с помощью editText.setEnabled(false);

Но если хотите именно вашим способом, то кладите `TextView` и `EditText` в одну разметку с `RelativeLayout` и играйтесь с видимостью `VISIBLE`/`GONE`.

Но первый вариант лучше

Comment: Как отключить при тапе в свободное место и включить,при тапе в поле? onFocusChanged() подходит?

Comment: повесте на "свободное место" слушать на editText.setEnabled(false), a на тап по "полю" editText.setEnabled(true), очевидно

Comment: https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20setonclicklistener%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: onFocusChaged() не подойдет я думаю

Comment: @morethanfish Я что то не понимаю, что вы хотите в итоге получить. При тапе на свободное место, EditText и так потеряет фокус и ввода туда не будет, а при тапе на него - будет опять. Опишите в вопросе логику, которая вам требуется наиболее подробно.

Comment: @pavlofff вариант выше меня устраивает,вот сейчас пытаюсь разобраться как повесить слушатель в пустое место.

Comment: @pavlofff сделал с помощью onTouchEvent().
Можно как-либо убрать полосу подчеркивания, при тапе в пустое место?

Comment: Сделал фон прозрачным и полоска пропала.